# Reformat Excel document before processing

Tags: excel, ssis

I recieve daily reports from an other department of my company that are formated like that :
[screenshot_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjkjb.png)

Is there a way, in SSIS, to reformat the document so it looks like this : [screenshot_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPW5H.png)

Or to ask SSIS to process the file from B4 to E{potentially infinite} ?

Comment: You could do that with a Excel add-in. One click when you open the file and it's done

Comment: Thanks for you replie, but I need this transformation to occur in SSIS and not Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in the excel source in the data flow, tell SSIS what to select from the excel file.

Right click the excel source, select properties:

- Change Data access mode to `SQL command`
- Then you can customize the SQL Command Text and customize the query with `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B4:E]`

`[Sheet1$B4:E]` will start at column B line 4 to column E to the end

[image]